# Why is csv "not implemented in Skulpt"?

Tags: python, csv, skulpt

I am trying to make a program that uses the functions `get_neg` and `get_pos`to gather information about the file called `project_twitter_data.csv` and create a a csv that contains the information about how many negative and positive words that there are. As you can see (I will copy/paste all my current code) on lines 4-7, I am just testing out trying to make a csv *without* any of the fancy stuff, but for some reason a get an error:

**

> NotImplementedError: csv is not yet implemented in Skulpt on line 1

**

I then Googled "What is Skulpt" and got a fat percentage measurer website. Could somebody please explain to a Python noob what the error means and how to fix it?

(PS here is the code):

```
#
import csv

with open('resulting_data.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['first line', '2nd line'])

punctuation_chars = ["'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '@']
# lists of words to use
positive_words = []
with open("positive_words.txt") as pos_f:
    for lin in pos_f:
        if lin[0] != ';' and lin[0] != '\n':
            positive_words.append(lin.strip())

negative_words = []
with open("negative_words.txt") as pos_f:
    for lin in pos_f:
        if lin[0] != ';' and lin[0] != '\n':
            negative_words.append(lin.strip())

twitter = []
with open("project_twitter_data.csv") as pos_f:
    for lin in pos_f:
        if lin[0] != ';' and lin[0] != '\n':
            twitter.append(lin.strip())
print(twitter)
#######################
def strip_punctuation(x):
    lst = []
    for letter in x:
        if not letter in punctuation_chars:
            lst.append(letter)
    return ("".join(lst))


######################
def get_neg(x):
    lst = []
    original_lst_name = []
    var = 0
    string = x.lower()
    original_lst_name = string.split(" ")
    print(original_lst_name)
    for letter in original_lst_name:
        if strip_punctuation(letter) in negative_words:
            var += 1
            print(var)
            print(letter)
    return (var)


#######################
def get_pos(x):
    lst = []
    original_lst_name = []
    var = 0
    string = x.lower()
    original_lst_name = string.split(" ")
    print(original_lst_name)
    for letter in original_lst_name:
        if strip_punctuation(letter) in positive_words:
            var += 1
            print(var)
            print(letter)
    return (var)
#########################
```

Comment: https://skulpt.org/ is a browser based version of Python from what I can tell. My guess is you're somehow using that and they don't yet support `csv`

Comment: thank you very much; yes, I should think that that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

try opening CSV file as text file instead and process it from there as a list.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).